# Grails 3.0.1 Asset Pipeline Assets not Linking in Production WAR

Tags: css, grails, asset-pipeline, war, grails-3.0

As the title states, CSS & JS are rendering in dev on localhost, they are also rendering when JAR file from package/war command is run.

Linking the asset manifest files.

```
<asset:stylesheet href="application.css" />
<asset:javascript src="application.js" />
```

grails-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require main  
*= require mobile
*= require bootstrap
*= require bootstrap-select
*= require_self
*/
```

grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed. 
//
//= require jquery-2.1.3.js
//= require bootstrap.js
//= require bootstrap-select.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Viewing the war generated with Jenkins using the war command, I see META-INF, WEB-INF, and assets directories. Inside the assets directory I see all of the files from grails-app/assets, plus the same files with different extensions such as .gz and .map as well as what appears to be hashes after the names of the files.

This is the source of the page rendering as a deployed WAR.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Knowledge Asset Inventory</title>


  </head>
  <body>
```

As you can see there are no stylesheets/scripts being linked here and the space where they are supposed to be is blank.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading `asset-pipeline` to version `3.0.8` seems to fix it.

```
runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:3.0.8"
```

Comment: This does fix it. There was also a fix released with Grails 3.0.5, so upgrading to that version should also fix the problem.